# Twitter's new API Url Returns the Error Message

Tags: twitter

I want to get total number of tweets of perticular user. But when i am accessing Twitter new 1.1 API 
[URL](http://gettwitterid.com/) then it shows me below kind of error message.

{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

For getting the Twitter's **user_id**, i am using this [website](http://gettwitterid.com/)

[1](http://gettwitterid.com/): https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=[my User ID]

Comment: Are you authenticating to the API first?

Comment: Yes, i registered my application on this url. [https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new]

Comment: In addition to that, your script must authenticate with the API using oAuth first, before making the API call to get the number of tweets. The error is showing that you're either not authenticating, or authentication is incorrect.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show. This url is correct for showing user's follower's count?

Comment: Thats correct, but on that documentation page you'll also see in the right column "Authentication required". The error you're getting is showing that you're not doing that first, or auth details are incorrect.

Comment: Yeh.. it shows me "Authentication Required" and i select the application and generate the Oath Signature. Now it shows me "OAuth signing results" and below the page the requested url and requested query is generated

Comment: @flaunster How do you authenticate?